# Using UDP sockets in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to communicate with UDP sockets via Chrome Extensions? I want to be able to have browser actions AND the ability to just send messages to UDP sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

You either have to use both an app and an extension that communicate, or use an extension and a [Native Host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host).